# How to style all elements of the same type except the hovered one?

Tags: css, hover

I want to style a row with four columns in it to change the opacity once hovered to 0.5 but the actually hovered column should still have an opacity of 1 so basically every col gets styled but the hovered one.

I tried stuff like:

```
div.airsuspension-submenu div.row div:hover .nav-highlight:not(div.airsuspension-submenu div.row div .nav-highlight:hover) {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

all hovered `div.row div` elements should have an opacity of 0.5, but the hovered `div.row div .nav-highlight` should still have an opacity of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best bet to do this without javascript would be to apply the background colour to the parent container and then lower the opacity on hover of the parent to all children and then increase the opacity of the specific element hovered over.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.d-flex:hover > div {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.d-flex:hover > div:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.item {
  background: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a heads up-- the user tagged `html` and `css` but your answer included `sass`-- if the OP isn't aware of that syntax this answer might not be particularly readable for them...

Comment: True that, changed my answer to css

Comment: `sass` was fine :) Thank you very much. Its almost perfect, but if no element if hovered it should stay at 100% opacity

Comment: @MarcelH. - _if no element if hovered it should stay at 100% opacity_ - I am pretty sure that that is the way this solution behaves-- I moved the code into a snippet and that is the behavior I'm seeing, give it a try...

Comment: Okay, my bad - had a typo... Thank you very much :)